# How to output object's parameter name in js templating engines (mustache, underscore)

Tags: javascript, template-engine, mustache, underscore.js

We have some array of objects:

```
data = [
{
'showname-array': [
    {'a':..}
    {'b':..}
    {'c':..}
]
},
{
'andanotherName-array': [
    {'a':..}
    {'b':..}
    {'c':..}
]
},
]
```

Is it possible to render with mustache or underscore.js-templates the name of object's property:
'showname-array'
'andanotherName-array'

```
<div> Hello , showing content of: <% showname-array %> </div>
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Underscore `_.keys()` function

```
temp = "<% _.each(_.keys(data), function(name){ %> 
        <div>Hello, showing content of '<%= name %>'</div>
        <% }); %>"
_.template(temp, data); // <div>Hello, showing content of 'showname-array'</div>
                        // <div>Hello, showing content of 'andanotherName-array'</div>
```